# How to merge common parts of qemu qcow2 disks

Tags: qemu, snapshot, qcow2

I have a qemu image `B.qcow2` that is a snapshot of `A.qcow2`.
I created a copy of `B.qcow2` by using `cp B.qcow2 C.qcow2` and then worked on both `B.qcow2` and `C.qcow2` independently. Thus, `B.qcow2` and `C.qcow2` are eventually different but they have a common part (since C.qcow2 was copied from B.qcow2).

In order to save disk place, I wanted to know if it is possible (by using qemu-img or programmatically) to create another image `common.qcow2` that will contain all common parts of `B.qcow2` and `C.qcow2`, then remove this common part from `B.qcow2` and `C.qcow2` and rebase the images in such a way that `B.qcow2` and `C.qcow2` are based on `common.qcow2` and `common.qcow2` are based on `A.qcow2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to have one base image, and two images containing the differences to that. This can be implemented in the following way:

0. To avoid confusion: `mv B.qcow2 common.qcow2`
1. Rebase common on A: `qemu-img rebase -b common.qcow2 A.qcow2`
2. Recreate B, based on common: `git create -b common B.qcow2`
3. Rebase C on common: `qemu-img rebase -b common.qcow2 C.qcow2`

of course, now B.qcow2 is an "empty shell" with no changes relatively to common, and C contains all the changes between A and B, but there's no way to save any more space, and assuming it doesn't matter which of the two files contains the changes, this is as good as any other solution.

Comment: Thus, it seems i didn't understood how rebase worked exactly. I believe it does not only change a pointer but also check for differences

Comment: In bullet 2., is that really `git create -b common` or could it be `qemu-img create -b common.img`?